# array overriding in my code only single value i am getting

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i am getting data from database there is so much data is there so I am planning display it in different places by using array but i tried code array is overriding ian not getting all objects values can any body clear this one.

```
CodeIgniter controller code:
   public function compare_by_business_sectors(){
       //print_r($this->input->post());exit;
        if($this->input->post())
        {
            $solution_array = array();
                //print_r (json_encode($business_sectors));exit;
            $business_sectors=$this->home_model->compare_business_sectors_data($this->input->post());
           // print_r($business_sectors);exit;
            $tab_child_id = "";
             $id="";
            foreach($business_sectors as $key=>$sectors){
                        $solution_array[1]=$sectors->solution_name;
                        $solution_array[2]=$sectors->description;
                        $solution_array[3]=$sectors->vendor_name;
                        $solution_array[4]=$sectors->video_presentation;
                        $solution_array[5]=$sectors->start_free_trail;
                        $solution_array[6]=$sectors->hardware_package;
                        $solution_array[7]=$sectors->pos_market_rating;
                  $id = "solution".$sectors->tab_child_id;
                 $solution_array[$id]=array();
                 if($tab_child_id != $sectors->tab_child_id){
                     $solution_array[$id][$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->title;
                  $tab_child_id=$sectors->tab_child_id;
                 }
                 else {
                 $solution_array[$id][$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->title;
                 }
            }          
          }

          print_r($solution_array);
   }
```

model_code:

```
public function compare_business_sectors_data($sectorid){
                    $query = $this->db->select('solutions.*,solution_tabs_child_fields.field_id,solution_tabs_child_fields.tab_child_id,solution_tabs_child_fields.title')
                             ->from('solutions')
                             //->join('solutions', 'business_sector.sector_id = solutions.business_sector_id',"left")
                             ->join('solution_features','solutions.entry_id  = solution_features.entry_id',"left")
                             ->join('solution_tabs_child_fields','solution_features.field_id = solution_tabs_child_fields.field_id')
                            ->where('solutions.business_sector_id', $sectorid['id'])
                            ->get();
                            return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as

```
$solution_array = array();
    //print_r (json_encode($business_sectors));exit;
$business_sectors=$this->home_model->compare_business_sectors_data($this->input->post());
// print_r($business_sectors);exit;
$tab_child_id = "";
 $id="";
foreach($business_sectors as $key=>$sectors)
{
    $solution_array[$key][1]=$sectors->solution_name;
    $solution_array[$key][2]=$sectors->description;
    $solution_array[$key][3]=$sectors->vendor_name;
    $solution_array[$key][4]=$sectors->video_presentation;
    $solution_array[$key][5]=$sectors->start_free_trail;
    $solution_array[$key][6]=$sectors->hardware_package;
    $solution_array[$key][7]=$sectors->pos_market_rating;
    $id = "solution".$sectors->tab_child_id;
    $solution_array[$key][$id]=array();
    if($tab_child_id != $sectors->tab_child_id)
    {
      $solution_array[$key][$id][$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->title;
      $tab_child_id=$sectors->tab_child_id;
    }
    else 
    {
      $solution_array[$key][$id][$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->title;
    }
}
```